# HP DL380 "no bootable device"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have HP DL380 Server running Windows Server 2012 R2. Now we have a problem with its startup. The error message is: "No bootable device. Please attach a legacy BIOS bootable device."

Comment: see dell.com/support: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000128655/no-boot-device-found-when-you-change-the-boot-sequence-to-legacy-mode-or-install-os-under-legacy-mode?lwp=rt  AND/OR (techlibrary.hpe.com) [Changing the Legacy BIOS boot order](https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/DL380_Gen9/setup_install/s_changing_legacy_boot.html)

Comment: and by the way 2012 r2 is a dead horse on 10/23 remember that you need to upgrade at least to 2019,better 2022

Comment: Even a minimally competent sysadmin can handle this. Hire someone who can do work for you.